# Using OSSOLOG in scratchbox (maemo development)

Tags: maemo, scratchbox

I am building a sharing-service for maemo5. In the example plugin they are calling `ULOG_INFO_L` at a lot of places, so I have adopted this for my service as well. The problem is that I can't find where the messages goes.

Reading osso-log.h I should define `DEBUG` or `OSSOLOGCOMPILE`, which I do and `OSSOLOG_STDOUT` or `OSSOLOG_SYSLOG`. I have tried both settings but can't get anything on syslog or stdout (I have no idea where stdout should end up since I am only calling af-sb-init.sh start), and it's not there anyway :-)

Anyone know where I can find my log?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that when using OSSOLOG_SYSLOG it actually logs to the host machine, not the scratchbox environment.